# Is there an equivalent of JMS in .NET?

Tags: .net, jms

Is there an equivalent of JMS in .NET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best equivalent to JMS in .NET is probably the combination of WCF with the MSMQ binding. MSMQ is a pub/sub message router, and with WCF wrapped around it, you get a nice, efficient little enterprise eventing service. The following article discusses how to manage message queues with WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731089.aspx

Comment: Does WCF Queue accept different backends? AFAIK, many message queue implementations provide JMS API so user can easily switch. This is very useful when migrating from local message queue to the cloud, such as [AWS SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-message-service-jms-client.html).

Answer (score 12):

The best equivalent is actually using JMS in .NET. This is possible with [Spring.NET](http://www.infoq.com/articles/jms-spring-messaging-interop).

Comment: However, would you recommend this - or would I be better off with MSMQ?

Comment: @Rajax- I'd only recommend this if you were going to integrate with Java JMS components. I thought I'd mention it so it gives you something to think about and is different from the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

Everytime I need to use a good lib I always start checking Apache Project, so look what I've found: [ActiveMQ NMS](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/)

Tale a look to this! Really recommended!

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite clear on your question. Are you asking if there is a JMS specification implementation in .NET?

It depends on what JMS provider you are using. If you are using WebSphere MQ as JMS provider, then there is [XMS .NET](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cgetstd_intronet.html) which is a JMS spec implementation for .NET.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at Microsoft Message Queuing or [MSMQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx) for short.  They're similar, but definitely not equivalent.

It's an easy system to work with and there are a ton of [resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=msmq) on the web for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with JMS but you can't beat NServiceBus for async messaging in .net (built on top of MSMQ). Check it out at http://www.nservicebus.com/